# Factory Design Pattern - defining methods in subclasses

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern, factory-method

I'm implementing a factory a class in charge of managing tokens across an application. I'll explain the problem I'm facing after this simplified example:

Suppose we have our factory class:

`TokenManagerFactory.java`:

```
public class TokenManagerFactory {

    public static TokenManager create(String tokenType)
    {
        if ("JWT".equals(tokenType))
            return new JwtTokenManagerImpl();

        return null;
    }


}
```

Then our `abstract interface`:

```
public abstract interface TokenManager {
    public  String       generateToken();
    public  boolean      verifyToken();
}
```

And finally the implementation `JwtTokenManagerImpl`:

```
public class JwtTokenManagerImpl implements TokenManager {
    //..Implementation of methods defined in interface (generateToken() and 
    //  verifyToken())

    public String aMethodNotDefinedInInterface() {
        return "A very cool String";
    }
}
```

Now in our `main` we want to create an instance of JwtTokenManager:

```
main {

    TokenManager tm = TokenManagerFactory.create("JWT");
    tm.aMethodNotDefinedInInterface(); // <-- Compilation error.

}
```

> The method aMethodNotDefinedInInterface() is undefined for the type
>   TokenManager

How do I adjust this design pattern so this error does not occur? Downcasting for when doing such calls seems like a harsh solution, is there a higher level adjustment I could make to accommodate this scenario?

Thanks.

---

I marked the solution I ended up using.

Comment: What does `aMethodNotDefinedInInterface` do? Additional initialization?

Comment: Why does `main` need to be aware of the specific type?  Is `JwtTokenManagerImpl` breaking single responsibility?  What is the purpose of `aMethodNotDefinedInInterface()`?

Comment: Why do you want to call an instance specific method there? It somehow renders the factory useless as it exists to abstract from the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `TokenManagerFactory` to accept an interface instead?

```
public interface JwtTokenManager extends TokenManager {
    String aMethodNotDefinedInInterface();
}

public class TokenManagerFactory {

    public static <T extends TokenManager> T create(Class<T> managerInterface) {
        if (managerInterface == JwtTokenManager.class) {
            return (T) new JwtTokenManagerImpl();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then where you use the factory can be something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JwtTokenManager tm = TokenManagerFactory.create(JwtTokenManager.class);
    tm.aMethodNotDefinedInInterface();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using this solution :)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I adjust this design pattern so this error does not occur?

You have to make a choice : either working with a base common type to manipulate all subclasses in an uniform way from the API of the base common type or casting it to a specific type to be able to invoke specific method of a subclass.

Some ideas to solve your issue :

- Add the method in the interface.
  If the method is expected for some implementations but not for all you could add it in the interface with a default implementation (that throws `UnsupportedOperationException` for example). You could override it in the subclass that wants to support it.
  It will work but will also do your code more brittle as the exception would be throw only at runtime.
- Provide an additional factory method that returns the concrete subclass in its declaration.
- Or as alternative enrich the actual method to return a generic type inferred by the target type specified in the return of the invoker. It is not type safe but it spares an explicit cast.

It would give something like :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends TokenManager> T create(String tokenType) {
    if ("JWT".equals(tokenType)) {
        return (T) new JwtTokenManagerImpl();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That you invoke :

```
JwtTokenManagerImpl token = create("JWT");
```

- Use the decorator pattern to enrich the behavior of some objects if it matches to your need.  You should rely on a common method in `TokenManager` that the decorator will enrich.
  You could so write something like :

`TokenManager tm = new TokenFooDecorator(TokenManagerFactory.create("JWT"));`

Answer (score 1):

If `aMethodNotDefinedInInterface()` is required for all Token managers, then it should be added to the interface.

---

Otherwise, this suggests that you need a different flow for each Token Manager, in which case you might want to use the [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) design pattern.

In this case, the **Implementor** hierarchy will be the token managers, and the **Abstraction** hierarchy will consist of the different flows implementations.
Then you can match the flow you want with the token implementation you want.

You'll still need to add the method to the interface, and either:

1. Add an empty implementation where its not relevant.
2. Throw `UnsupportedOperationException` exception, indicating that the flow/token manager combination is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to talk about what is wrong with your design first:

Here is your code:

```
TokenManager tm = TokenManagerFactory.create("JWT");
tm.aMethodNotDefinedInInterface(); // <-- Compilation error.
```

The question is, why does the create method take a token when you only have one possible value for that token? You might as well always return the concrete type.

You are going to tell me that you might want to do this:

```
String token = getTokenFromSomewhere(); // it may or may not be JWT
TokenManager tm = TokenManagerFactory.create(token);
tm.aMethodNotDefinedInInterface(); // <-- Compilation error.
```

In that case, you don't know what type of `TokenManager` you have returned, so you can't call a method on it unless it is in the interface.

You might now say that you would want to do either of the two cases - with a known token or an unknown token. In this case, the known token case is a bit of a mis-use of the factory method since its design is to return any type of token. You are using the factory in two different ways. You could therefore either create a specific factory method for the particular token, or just use a cast.

Comment: The factory expects the token type, in this case the token type is JWT, it isn't the actual token. But your solution is clear, thanks :)

Comment: The point is that if you know the token (the token is a literal) then there is no point in passing a token: you might as well have another method. If you don't know the token, you can't assume anything about the return value.

Answer (score 0):

A method Not Defined In the Interface, cannot be invoked using the  Interface type. So the reference variable tm of Interface type TokenManager has to be cast to one of the sub type, before invoking the specific method(that is not in the interface, but in the specific class).

```
if (tm instanceof JwtTokenManagerImpl ) {
  JwtTokenManagerImpl  jwtTm = (JwtTokenManagerImpl) tm;
  jwtTm.aMethodNotDefinedInInterface();
}
```